# How to navigate from one activity to another activity

Tags: java, android, eclipse

i am trying to navigate between different pages on an Android application, when I run the project it takes me to the Emulator screen but an error message appears:

[image]

The following is the code in the .java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
    this, R.array.MyPictures, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);


    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button02);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            setContentView(R.layout.imageview);
        }
    });

}
```

LogCat:

```
02-27 11:58:41.374: D/AndroidRuntime(313): Shutting down VM
02-27 11:58:41.374: W/dalvikvm(313): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
02-27 11:58:41.454: E/AndroidRuntime(313): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-27 11:58:41.454: E/AndroidRuntime(313): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test/com.example.test.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-27 11:58:41.454: E/AndroidRuntime(313):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
02-27 11:58:41.454: E/AndroidRuntime(313):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
02-27 11:58:41.454: E/AndroidRuntime(313):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
02-27 11:58:41.454: E/AndroidRuntime(313):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
02-27 11:58:41.454: E/AndroidRuntime(313):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-27 11:58:41.454: E/AndroidRuntime(313):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-27 11:58:41.454: E/AndroidRuntime(313):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
02-27 11:58:41.454: E/AndroidRuntime(313):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-27 11:58:41.454: E/AndroidRuntime(313):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-27 11:58:41.454: E/AndroidRuntime(313):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
02-27 11:58:41.454: E/AndroidRuntime(313):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
02-27 11:58:41.454: E/AndroidRuntime(313):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-27 11:58:41.454: E/AndroidRuntime(313): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-27 11:58:41.454: E/AndroidRuntime(313):  at com.example.test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29)
02-27 11:58:41.454: E/AndroidRuntime(313):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
02-27 11:58:41.454: E/AndroidRuntime(313):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
02-27 11:58:41.454: E/AndroidRuntime(313):  ... 11 more
```

is there any mistake am not aware of ???

this is my second project which shows the same Error
thanks

Comment: Post your logcat message.

Comment: what is `line no 29` in `MainActivity`

Comment: You can not set two times "setContentView()" in one Activity as per "InnocentKiller" answer your question just Remove setContentView(R.layout.imageview); from button click.And do proper action.if You want to change layout or setContentView() use animation for that.

Comment: @user3208016, try my below solution and let me know what happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have

```
final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button02);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            setContentView(R.layout.imageview);
        }
    });
```

Remove this `setContentView(R.layout.imageview);` from button click.  also remove `final` and declare `spinner` and `button` globally.

So your button click event should something like this.

```
final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button02);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                // Do something here
            }
        });
```

basically your full activity goes something like this.

```
Button button;
Spinner spinner; 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
    this, R.array.MyPictures, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);


    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button02);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
          Intent mSignup = new Intent(activityOne.this, activityTwo.class);
          startActivity(mSignup);
        }
    });

}
```

If you are using imageview then set it in onCreate method and then try.

Comment: so how the button is going to take me to the other page imageview ??

Comment: See i have updated code of button click in my answer, just change activity name of your's with mine.

Comment: And also if you want to go to other activity then don't forget to update `manifest` file. you have to register your activity in manifest file.